# Java swing timer does not set visibility of JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I write a card game with server and client (multi client). And I need to check every second if game is started or game is shut down. So I write a java.swing.timer to check it. But it doesn't set visibility of JPanel when  game is started. (Sorry for bad English)

That is code segment

```
public void checkGameState() {

    ActionListener action;

    timer = new Timer(delay, (ActionEvent e) -> {
        try {
            boolean isEnd = checkIfGameIsClose();
            if (isEnd == true) {
                System.out.println("---->"+isEnd);
                mainGamePanel.setVisible(false);
                waitRoomPanel.setVisible(true);
                availability_button.setText("Ready");
                availability_button.setBackground(Color.red);
                availability_status = false;
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            boolean isStart = checkIfGameIsOpen();
            if (isStart == true) {
                System.out.println("---->"+isStart);
                mainGamePanel.setVisible(true);
                waitRoomPanel.setVisible(false);
                clientConnectToServer.isEndTheGame();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
    timer.start();


}

public boolean checkIfGameIsClose() throws IOException {
    boolean isClosedGame = clientConnectToServer.checkifGameIsEnd();
    System.out.println(isClosedGame + " ---> Close");
    return isClosedGame;
}

public boolean checkIfGameIsOpen() throws IOException {
    boolean gameIsStart = clientConnectToServer.startGame();
    System.out.println(gameIsStart + "---> open");
    return gameIsStart;
}
```

Then game is started method checkIfGameIsOpen() return true.
Then game is shut down method checkIfGameIsClose() return true.

mainGamePanel is Panel what should appear when game is started.

Comment: Did you validate/layout the parent panel, when visibility of child changed?

Comment: Call the methods `revalidate()` and `repaint()` for the container of your panels (or for the root pane of the window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems and possible solutions:

1. You change the visibility state of JPanels but don't notify the container that holds them that you've done this. You should call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on this container after making all such changes. The first, revalidate, tells the container and its layout managers to re-layout all contained components, and the second, repaint, requests that the JVM re-draw the container and all its children. This will help rid the container of "dirty" pixels.
2. Much better would be to use a CardLayout to swap visibility, then you wouldn't need what I mention above. The tutorial can be found here: [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).
3. You don't tell us if your debug println's are showing.
4. Your current solution is to use intermittent polling of the server's game state, a brittle kludge solution. Much better is to use a notification solution where the server notifies all clients of changes in game state, and then the clients can act on this notification.

Comment: @BenAfleek: then you've likely got other problems in code that you're not showing us. Consider creating and posting a [mcve] code with your question.